# How to groupby datetime column by starting day of week in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime, pandasql

I have the following dataframe:

```
transaction_date      gp    
2017-01-17         3477.92  
2017-01-18         5839.64  
2017-01-19         5082.19  
2017-01-20         5761.63  
2017-01-21         6705.89  
2017-01-22         9937.17  
2017-01-23         9432.93  
2017-01-24         7965.56  
2017-01-25         8517.26  
2017-01-26         8098.36  
2017-01-27         8947.25  
2017-01-28         8473.38  
2017-01-29         11660.13 
2017-01-30         10266.24 
2017-01-31         4350.21  
2017-02-01         10820.15 
2017-02-02         8554.61  
2017-02-03         10689.69
```

i need to group by `transaction_date` column by starting day of it week , for example for all transaction between 2017-01-23 to 2017-01-30 it should be `Jan-23`
so basically i need a new column 'first_day_week' that shows starting day of the week that transaction happened in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you can convert the datetime series object to a period object having the desired weekly frequency. Access it's `start_time` attribute to get the starting day of every week later. Since we're operating on a series object, remember to provide the `.dt` accessor each time while carrying out *datetime* related operations.

```
df.assign(first_day_week=
          df['transaction_date'].dt.to_period('W').dt.start_time.dt.strftime("%b-%d"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `.dt` methods

## Data definition

```
s = pd.Series(data={
'2017-01-17':3477.92,  
'2017-01-18':5839.64,  
'2017-01-19':5082.19,  
'2017-01-20':5761.63,  
'2017-01-21':6705.89,  
'2017-01-22':9937.17,  
'2017-01-23':9432.93,  
'2017-01-24':7965.56,  
'2017-01-25':8517.26,  
'2017-01-26':8098.36,  
'2017-01-27':8947.25,}  )
transaction_date = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(s.index))
```

## Getting the start of the week

```
start_of_week = transaction_date - pd.to_timedelta(transaction_date.dt.weekday, unit='D')
start_of_week
```

## Returns

```
0    2017-01-16
1    2017-01-16
2    2017-01-16
3    2017-01-16
4    2017-01-16
5    2017-01-16
6    2017-01-23
7    2017-01-23
8    2017-01-23
9    2017-01-23
10   2017-01-23
```

This can be assigned to a start of the week column

## Formatting

if the formatting is important, you can add

```
start_of_week = start_of_week.dt.strftime('%b-%d')
```